# How to calculate a c-index

Tags: stata

Is there any Stata code for calculating the `c-index` (also known as c-statistics and concordance statistics), for fine gray?

I found an R package that does this but I have no idea how to do it in Stata.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following is what you are looking for:

```
webuse lbw, clear

logit low age lwt i.race smoke ptl ht ui
lroc

Logistic model for low

number of observations =      189
area under ROC curve   =   0.7462
```

The last line reports the `c-statistic`.

Type `help lroc` from Stata's command prompt for more information.

---

**EDIT:**

I just noticed that you mention "Fine-Gray" so i assume that you are referring to survival analysis regression. The *community-contributed* command `somersd` does what you want in Stata.

You can get its latest version from here:

```
net describe somersd, from(http://www.rogernewsonresources.org.uk/stata12)
```

After you install the package, type `help somersd` for additional details and syntax.

An example from the author's help file illustrates its use:

```
use http://www.stata-press.com/data/r9/drugtr, clear

generate youth = 100 - age
generate byte censind = 1 - died

somersd studytime drug youth, tr(c) cenind(censind)

Somers' D with variable: studytime
Transformation: Harrell's c
Valid observations: 48

Symmetric 95% CI for Harrell's c
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |              Jackknife
   studytime |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
        drug |   .7275986   .0367931    19.78   0.000     .6554855    .7997117
       youth |   .6415771   .0528314    12.14   0.000     .5380295    .7451246
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```